# If i mount the view structure inside my controller, am i going out of MVC pattern?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view

If I have following code in my controller:

```
 $this->view->print = "<form method='{$method}'> //Some form things </form>";
```

And then I use execute `echo $this->print;` in my view, am I going out of the MVC pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are definitely not using it. The controller should not be responsible for presentation logic. That is the task for view instances. It means, *no HTML in controllers*.

Views in MVC design pattern are structures which deal with presentation logic and manipulate multiple templates. **View is not a template.**

Also, if possible, controller should not be rendering the view. Controller should be responsible for sending messages to view and model layer, which then cause change of state in said parts of MVC.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm remodeling the structure.